# Vue - passing filter criteria when filtering array in methods

Tags: javascript, filter, vue.js, arguments

I was trying to filter listItems by filterCriteria before rendering.
The problem is that when I use Array.prototype.filter, I can't pass the filterCriteria into the filter function.
Is there any good way to pass it in without creating a new function?
Thanks!

```js
var todoList = new Vue({
 el: '#todolist',
 data: {
    // I want to use filterCriteria in data as filter criteria
  filterCriteria: 'Done',
  listItems: [
   {
    content: 'Fishing.',
    status: 'Done',
   },
   {
    content: 'Do homework.',
    status: 'Ongoing',
   }
  ],
 },
 methods: {
  filterList(listItems) {
   return listItems.filter(function(item) {
        // Ideally the 'Ongoing' here should be "filterCriteria" in data property
     return item.status === 'Ongoing';
   });
  }
 },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js"></script>
  <div id="todolist">
      <div class="list-filter">
        <a href="#">Ongoing</a>
        <a href="#">Done</a>
      </div>
   <div v-for="item in filterList(listItems)" class="list-item">
    <span class="list-status">{{item.status}}</span>
    <span class="list-content">{{item.content}}</span>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...can't pass the filterCriteria into the filter function.
>   Is there any good way to pass it in without creating a new function?

Yes, it is. First, simplier, use arrow function for callback:

```
filtered () {
  return this.items.filter(item => item.status === this.query)
}
```

Second, legacy, save `this` object reference:

```
filtered () {
  var vm = this
  return this.items.filter(function (item) {
    item.status === vm.query
  })
}
```

Complete example:

```js
var todoList = new Vue({
  el: '#todolist',
  data: {
    query: 'Done',
    items: [
      {content: 'Fishing.', status: 'Done'},
      {content: 'Do homework.', status: 'Ongoing'}
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    filtered () {
      return this.items.filter(item => item.status === this.query)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="todolist">
  <div>
    <button @click="query='Ongoing'">Ongoing</button>
    <button @click="query='Done'">Done</button>
  </div>
  <div v-for="item, idx in filtered" :key="idx">
    <span>{{item.status}}:</span>
    <span>{{item.content}}</span>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
```

Comment: Cool! But why using arrow function works? Is that because of no {} ?

Comment: No. Its because they have no own `this` object, as regular function have. The `this` value of the enclosing execution context is used instead. And this makes arrow functions ideal for callbacks - as they have `this` inherited / same as "parent" function - caller.

Comment: Glad to help :)